# If/else statement on Test-WSMan

Tags: powershell, user-interface, if-statement

I'm trying to create a Powershell GUI function to show a Connected/Not connected status via a color bar, computername inserted via a TextBox input.

I'm using Test-WSMan function to have my output.

I'm a bit confused with my else/if statement.

It should pop-up a window if no computer inserted, if no test-WSMan is possible it throw a red error if connects it should have a green lights.

Even with an unknown computer i allways have green light and my code don't stop running.

Here's my code

```
function checkinfo {

$Server=$textboxComputername.text;

if (-not $textboxComputername.Text)
            {
                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('No computer 
                specified', 'Error')
                Throw 'No Computer specified'
            }
elseif 

            (Test-WSMan  $Server ) {
            $label_PingStatus.Text = "OK";
            $label_PingStatus.ForeColor = "green"
            Write-Status -Message "Connected to $Server"
            $picturebox1.BackColor = "Green"
else 

            If (-not (Test-WSMan $Server))
            {
                $picturebox1.BackColor = "Red"
                Write-Status -Message "Not Connected to $Server"

                [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('No such computer or computer is offline', 'Error')
                Throw 'No such computer or computer is offline'

    }
```

Thanks for your guidance

Comment: This code doesn't even run without error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code as specified doesn't even run

Start from here:

```
Function checkinfo {
    $Server=$textboxComputername.text;
    If (-not $Computername) {
        [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('No computer specified', 'Error')
        Throw 'No Computer specified'
    }
    Else {
        If (Test-WSMan  $Server ) {
            Write-Host "Connected to $Server"
        }
        Else {
            Write-Host "Not Connected to $Server"
            [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show('Not connected', 'Error')
            Throw 'Test-WsMan failed'
        }
   }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Scepticalist, previous code didn't run probably due to this variable that i didn't mentionned function Write-Status
 {
  [cmdletbinding()]
  param
  (
   [Parameter(Mandatory)]
   [ValidateNotNull()]
   [String]$Message
   
  )
  $statusbar1.Text = $Message
 }

Comment: It works better thank you, but it's still trowing an error on ELSE statement. @Scepticalist Is this because script continues to run even if Test-WSMan fails? How can i stop it as well? Thanks for the help one more time

Comment: To stop it, just THROW an error in the ELSE statement - see above